# Debouncer doesn't call the function

Tags: javascript, debouncing

I have rewritten a debouncer function based on numerous ones I've found online and I'd like to understand why my previous flawed implementation worked while the ones from spec do not.

In both versions I use the following to test it:

```js
debounce(() => {
 console.log('the output was debounced');
}, 1000);
```

My original working but improperly scoped implementation (in a module called `debounce.js`):

```js
const DEFAULT_TIME = 100;
let timeoutId = 0;

export default function debounce(callback, time = DEFAULT_TIME) {
  if (!callback) {
    console.warn('No function supplied to debounce');
    return;
  }

  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }

  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
  }, time);
}
```

This works by saving the timeout ID scoped to the module and executing callback at the end of the timeout.

The common consensus seems to be the following [Source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/):

```js
export default function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
```

which should call the function at the end of the timeout. However when I use this method, it doesn't execute the function unless I also add `()` to the end to execute the function:

```js
debounce(() => {
 console.log('the output was debounced');
}, 1000)();
```

or alternatively executing the function within the debouncer

```js
export default function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (function (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  })();
}
```

Is this maybe something to do with the fact that the function is being exported?

Edit:
I have also attempted to export the function like this

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
export default debounce;
```

which does wait until the end of the timeout but then executes all of the functions at once. This seems to be because the timer (ID) is undefined as it's not in scope to the `clearTimeout()` function

Comment: well a big flaw with the first. one is using global variable so if you use it more than once they all share the same timer. Your code is forcing you to use `debounce` every time you want to execute a function, that is not how debounce is designed.

Comment: `function unless I also add () to the end to execute the function:` Yes that is how it works. It returns a function which is assigned to whatever is using it. It is wrapping the function you provide and returns a new function that is executed by whatever.

Comment: I haven't seen any of the debouncers require the extra `()` to be added: 
`debounce(() => { console.log('test') })() // <--this last ()`

Comment: because most people are doing . `foo.addEventListener('click', debounce(()=>console.log('clicked'), 500));` There is NO need to call it because the function is assigned. You need to EXECUTE the function, you are not running the function when you create it. You create the "wrapper" function. You then use that wrapper function to do the debouncing.

Comment: interesting - so the execution comes from being used in the handler

Comment: Yes, it is basically doing this when you click a bunch of times. `var foo = debounce(()=>console.log(1)); foo(); foo(); foo(); foo();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A debounce function is a function that returns another function which creates a closure around the function parameters and the timer variable.

This function that is returned is what is called by the code, you do not call debounce every time. The function is not triggered right away with most debounce implementations. It is called at the end after the timeout.

So each time the returned function is called, the function clears the timeout from the previous time it was called and creates a new timeout. You repeat that process every time it is called.

Basic example below is we create the debounce code and store it into a variable. We then call that function over and over again. The result should be one console.log line that is 100 milliseconds after the last call.

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return ((...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  });
}

const myClicker = debounce(() => { console.log('clicked'); }, 100);

myClicker();
myClicker();
myClicker();
myClicker();
myClicker();
```

Now most cases we are using debounce on event listeners to prevent things being called multiple times when user anger clicks a button multiple times.

In example below click the first button a bunch of times in a rapid fashion and see all the logs. After that click the second button in the same manner and see the difference. You will get one log 300 milliseconds after the last click.

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 300) {
  let timer;
  return ((...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, timeout);
  });
}


const clicked = (e) => console.log('clicked', e.target.id);

document.querySelector('#thrash').addEventListener('click', clicked);

document.querySelector('#debounced').addEventListener('click', debounce(clicked));
```

```html
<button id="thrash">Thrash it</button>
<button id="debounced">Thrash it (debounced)</button>
```

Your implementation is basically doing this without a closure. You are maintaining things in the global scope so only one of these debounce calls could be used on a page.

Comment: Thanks for the response - answer added